# CSS for larger monitors

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm working on the front end design of a website and need some help regarding the sizing of elements.  The web page layout/sizing of elements looks great on my 19", 1440x900 resolution monitor but when I view the same page on a larger HD monitor, all of the content is tiny.  Are there certain CSS units of measurement I should be using so the page looks the same no matter the size/resolution of the monitor?  I'm new to front end design so I'm uncertain when it comes to *standard* practices.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a media style query system to design your site to specific pixel ratios. I'll show you some small examples I use a lot for handheld media queries.

**iPad portrait:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px ) {
    // This media query would be appropriate for iPad portrait queries.
}
```

**iPhone, iPod Touch, Android Devices (same size):**

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 767 px) {
    // This media query would be appropriate for iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android.
}
```

You can of course use this for large monitor queries, because primarily css is not exactly a one size fits all deal. I hope this helped in a way, I continuously check my answers so if you comment I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i would recoment you use a framework to handle all your front end including scalability and theres a particular one called bootstrap http://www.getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html

there you'll get all the info you need to create a modern ui and what you want

Comment: If he were to rely on a framework all of his life he wouldn't get anywhere, he needs to learn how to produce the scalability and responsive design without depending on such a thing as bootstrap. Now for someone who is learning web design, bootstrap is a good framework to learn exactly how to produce that scalability and responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

You could use % to make everything relative, but that's bad practice and defeats the whole purpose of having varying resolutions.

Look into responsive design.

Comment: Using percentages is not exactly a bad practice, just wouldn't recommend it if you are looking to do a very responsive site design. I would recommend percentages over specific pixel sizes though.

Comment: Right, it's not! I just assumed if he wanted everything to look the same, then EVERYTHING would be in %, and that, is bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this website](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.html) is a good starting point. They explain, which units you can use in css and where to use which of these.

For example if you write text on your page, it's recommended to use `em` as the unit as it automatically adapts to the users device's standard font size. E.g. 2em means 2 times the size of the current font.

As some of the other answers have pointed out, it also is a good idea to have a look at the css properties [`max-width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) and [`max-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp). At some point - when the resolution is high enough, your website will stretch over the whole site and the text is not easy to read anymore. So it may be a good idea to set some of these properties to limit the maximum width of a website.

Well, and the third thing you may like to consider is to use a predefined css-framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which helps you to easily and more important very fast design a great looking website. This of course will not work in all cases (e.g. when you need to fit a corporate design or something), but in most cases (e.g. if you just want a easy to use webinterface for something), bootstrap is worth a consideration.

However, you also asked if there are any "standard" practices. I would say that there are some kind of recommendations and "often used" practices, but it also is some kind of up to you which way you like to go and which specific requirements there are for your website.

I hope this answer helped you and gave you a point to start.